# Setting a cookie for all requests in spring

Tags: java, spring

So what I want to do is set a cookie for all requests based on a certain context-specific bean. I have a bean `contextBean`, which various components can write to (it is thread-safe) and for every request, the updated context is then written as a cookie. However, using a `Filter` does not work because:

```
doFilter(request, response, chain) {
    chain.doFilter();
    response.addCookie(...);
}
```

`response.isCommitted()` is `true` after running the chain and the same problem exists with a `HandlerInterceptor` if the controller is annotated with `@ResponseBody` (it does seem to work for methods without `ResponseBody`). Is there a way to do this for all handlers?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, setting cookie in the post-process phase does not work. So do your validation and then set it in the pre-process phase of the filter.

That is :

```
doFilter(request, response, chain) {
    response.addCookie(...);
    chain.doFilter();
}
```